# Replace name of a file with the first line of its contents

Tags: c++, file, filenames, rename

I have multiple files with extension *.txt and inside this files i want to read their first line and rename into a file name.

For example:   file.txt

and inside this file, the first line is:   X_1_1.1.X_1_X

and rename it into:   X_1_1.1.X_1_X.txt

I have rewritten this code from other projects but it renames my file into random letters and dont know how to correct it

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()

{
   int size=28000;
   string *test = new string[rozmiar];
   std::fstream file;
   std::string line;
   file.open("C:\\file.txt",std::ios::in);  
   int line_number=0;
   while((file.eof() != 1))
   {
    getline(file, line);
    test[line_number]=line;
    line_number++;
   }

   file.close();
   cout << "Enter line number in the file to be read: \n";
   cin >> line_number;
   cout << "\nYour line number is:";
   cout << test[0] << " \n";
   char newname[25];
   test[0]=newname;
   int result;
   char oldname[] ="C:\\file.txt";
   result= rename(oldname , newname);

   if (result == 0)
      puts ("File successfully renamed");
   else
      perror("Error renaming file");
}
```

Thanks for help
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer to your code directly as that looks like it's already been handled, but this should do what you want assuming you only need the first line (sans error checking)

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    static std::string const filename("./test.txt");

    std::string line;
    {
        std::ifstream file(filename.c_str()); // c_str() not needed if using C++11
        getline(file, line);
    }

    rename(filename.c_str(), (line + ".txt").c_str());
}
```

Comment: Ok thank You very much. Both answers worked correctly. But next thing..how to change static file name("./test.txt") into all files in the folder with extension txt?

Comment: @VictorVector this will take a list of filenames from the standard input, and rename each one according to the first line: http://pastebin.com/RG7w3AUH  you can use it like this in windows (if the app is named 'app.exe': `dir /b *.txt | app.exe` , linux and mac can use `ls *.txt | app.exe`

Answer (score 1):

You do not initialize `newname` in any way. This is the problem.

You want something like this:

```
result= rename(oldname , test[0].c_str());
```

(and remove `newname`).

In your code `newname` is completely uninitialized, thus you are seeing random characters in your filename.